# Rails Engines: Where to define gems only used in testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rails-engines, gemfile, gemspecs

I'm building an engine, and I want to use VCR and Webmock for testing.

The documentation within the [Gemfile generated when an engine is created](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/ec8d8652f36bc4bf2ea19b8f7dd264187efc99ae/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/plugin/templates/Gemfile), seems to suggest that all an engine's gems should be loaded via gemspec, but the only options for this are add_dependency and add_development_dependency. If I use the latter, VCR and Webmock get loaded into my development environment, and I then have to explicitly disable Webmock in the development environment. I'd rather not do that as a host app may want these gems to work in development, and my engine disabling them may be unexpected.

The obvious solution would appear to be to use the engine's Gemfile:

```
group :test do
  gem 'vcr'
  gem 'webmock'
end
```

Is this the right way to load gems that are only used when testing an engine?

Are there any gotchas doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the answer is that there is nothing wrong with declaring in an engine's Gemfile, gems only used for testing and debugging the engine code. Further, I think the Gemfile template should be made less ambiguous, and have submitted a pull request to this effect:

https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/11881

Comment: @MattW. Yours is the first criticism I have received for this answer. My pull request was not laughed out of github. The only discussion was around the wording - not the strategy. If you could suggest a better way of ensuring a gem needed when testing an engine, only gets loaded in that environment then I would welcome it. If you want a test case, add web_mock to an engine via `add_development_dependency` and then try calling an external service from the development environment.

Answer (score 0):

One of the well known rails engines, rails_admin (https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin) uses that approach, so I believe it can be considered a good practice.

Comment: That's an interesting example. However, I notice that they also define  gems to only be used in development. For example pry in: https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/blob/bba8cba7e7e9391f653057ac12e119f532ffd6ba/Gemfile. Is this bad practice? If so would that make this example a bad "good practice" example?

Answer (score 0):

What's the load order for Rails app and Rails app's Rails Engines?

My guess is that the Rails app Gemfile is the determining factor for a gem being loaded or not loaded. This might be worth a try in a Rails test app.

Comment: The code example I've added works. I am not asking what works, but rather what is best practice.

Comment: Sorry, looking at this again, I realise your answer is relevant. The load order determines whether the gems would be loaded into the host app's test environment. Good point!